# How can I add MySQL transaction in a PDO class?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rollback, autocommit

I have a PDO class that I created the help me connect and communicate with MySQL server.
What I am trying to do add a function or a method to the class that will help me open a transaction to MySQL along with commit and rollback. I never used commit and rollback.

What will make scene I think is somehow stop the auto commit every time this class is called and rollback whenever an error is thrown and commit every time this class id closed.

my 2 question are:
1) is it a good idea to open a connection then run multiple queries the commit if there is no errors otherwise rollback then close the connection?
2) How call I manage to add this to my existing class?
The is my current PHP class

```
<?php

class connection {

    private $connString;
    private $userName;
    private $passCode;
    private $server;
    private $pdo;
    private $errorMessage;
    private $pdo_opt = array();
    protected $lastQueryTime;
    protected $lastQuery;
    protected $effectedRows;



    function __construct($dbName = DATABASE_NAME, $serverName = DATABASE_HOST){

        //SET PDO options
        if(TESTING_ENVIRONMENT == 1){
            $this->pdo_opt[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            $this->pdo_opt[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE]  = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;
        }

            $this->pdo_opt[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES utf8';
            $this->pdo_opt[PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING]  = PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8;

        //sets credentials
        $this->setConnectionCredentials($dbName, $serverName);

        //start the connect
        $this->startConnection();

    }

    function startConnection(){


            $this->pdo = new PDO($this->connString, $this->userName, $this->passCode, $this->pdo_opt);

            if( ! $this->pdo){

                $this->errorMessage  = 'Failed to connect to database. Please try to refresh this page in 1 minute. ';
                $this->errorMessage .= 'However, if you continue to see this message please contact your system administrator.';
                echo $this->getError();
            }
    }


    //this will close the PDO connection
    public function endConnection(){

        $this->pdo = null;
    }

    //return a dataset with the results
    public function getDataSet($query, $data = NULL)
    {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );

        $cmd->execute($data);
        $this->effectedRows = $cmd->rowCount();
        $ret = $cmd->fetchAll();
        //$cmd->closeCursor();
        $this->lastQueryTime = microtime(true) - $start;
        $this->lastQuery = $query;

        return $ret;
    }



    public function processQuery($query, $data = NULL)
    {
        $start = microtime(true);
               //$this->pdo->beginTransaction();


        $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );
        $ret = $cmd->execute($data);
               //$this->pdo->commit();
               //$cmd->closeCursor();
        $this->effectedRows = $cmd->rowCount();
        $this->lastQueryTime = microtime(true) - $start;
        $this->lastQuery = $query;

        return $ret;
    }


    //return last insert id
    public function lastInsertId($name = NULL) {
        if(!$this->pdo) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->pdo->lastInsertId($name);
    }


    //return last insert id
    public function rowCount() {

        return $this->effectedRows;
    }


    public function getOneResult($query, $data = NULL){
        $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );
        $cmd->execute($data);

        return $cmd->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function getError(){
        if($this->errorMessage != '')
            return $this->errorMessage;
        else
            return true;  //no errors found

    }

    //this where you need to set new server credentials with a new case statment
    function setConnectionCredentials($dbName, $serv){

        switch($serv){

            //the defaults are predefined in the APP_configuration file - DO NOT CHANGE THE DEFAULT
            default:
                $this->connString   = 'mysql:host='.DATABASE_HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE_NAME.';charset=utf8';
                $this->userName     = DATABASE_USERNAME;
                $this->passCode     = DATABASE_PASSWORD;
            break;

            }

    }

public function lastQueryTime() {
    if(!$this->lastQueryTime) {
        throw new Exception('no query has been executed yet');
    }
    return $this->lastQueryTime;
}

public function lastQuery() {
    if(!$this->lastQuery) {
        throw new Exception('no query has been executed yet');
    }
    return $this->lastQuery;
}

}

?>
```

**EDITED**
after gathering notice is this way I need??

```
$db = new connection();
$db->beginTransaction(); //begin transaction
$db->processQuery();     //process query #1
$db->processQuery();     //process query #2
$db->commit();           //commit changes
$db->endConnection();    //close connection


public function beginTransaction(){
    $this->pdo->beginTransaction(); 
}

public function commit(){
    $this->pdo->commit(); 
}

public function rollBack(){
    $this->pdo->rollBack(); 
}   

//this will close the PDO connection
public function endConnection(){
    $this->pdo = null;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add PDO's beginTransaction and other corresponding methods?

Comment: Where would I add them? some time I need to call different methods during one transaction

Comment: If you have no idea how to use them - are you sure you need transactions at all?

Comment: I do because sometimes I have an insert that depends of another insert or update. So i don't want to update unless the previous insert took plase

Answer (score 0):

[PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)

```
/* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
$dbh->beginTransaction();
```

[PDO::commit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

```
/* Commit the changes */
$dbh->commit();
```

At this point, it feels like your `connection` class is fairly low level. My guess is it does not have enough information to know by itself when begin a transaction and when to commit it. You probably have to provide the corresponding methods (as well as a `rollback` method) and let the user of your class to call them if/when needed.

---

Concerning yours questions, transaction are not only to rollback local changes. It is also about [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29). That is sequences of operations that will either be *all done* or *not done at all*. Don't forget there will be concurrent access to your DB. Sometimes you don't want someone to change the data while you are manipulating them.

Comment: Where would I add this? sometime i would need to run this method getDataSet couple of time and then run perocessQuery couple times before I commit the changes.

Comment: I am not sure if I am clear on the solution. I have updated my question at the very bottom. please review that and tell me if this is what are you advising? if this is what you are telling me can you please tell me when and how will i be using the rollback method?